# Operators precedence of "or" and assignment

Tags: php, operators, assignment-operator

Found some interesting code snippet today. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
$var = null;

$var or $var = '123';

$var or $var = '312';

var_dump($var);
```

The thing is that, as i know, [precedence of assignment is higher that `OR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), so, as i assume, `var_dump` should output `312` (first - assign, second - compare logically). But result is defferent, i getting `123` (first - check if `$var` converting to `true`, second - if not, assign value).

The questions is how does it work?

Why behavior is the same for `or` and `||`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see examples about this behaviour in [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Also you can read artical about [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

> The short-circuit expression `x Sand y` (using Sand to denote the short-circuit variety) is equivalent to the conditional expression `if x then y else false;` the expression `x Sor y` is equivalent to `if x then true else y`.

In php.

```
return x() and y();
```

equal to

```
if (x())
  return (bool)y();
else
  return false;
```

---

```
return x() or y();
```

equal to

```
if (x())
  return true;
else
  return (bool)y();
```

So, deal is not just in precedence.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you! So, the reason is that `Short-circuit operators are, in effect, control structures rather than simple arithmetic operators`

Answer (score 3):

It same as

```
$var = null;

if(!$var)$var = '123';
if(!$var)$var = '321';

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: I know that these are the same. I want to know how does it work

Comment: It execute string after `or` (in your case `$var = '123';`) only if statement before `or` is `empty/false/null/etc...`